# Is there a way to emit end event to all listeners at the same time with Node.js EventEmitter?

Tags: javascript, node.js

As [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_emit_event_arg1_arg2) says, `emitter.emit(event[, arg1][, arg2][, ...])`

> Synchronously calls **each of the listeners** registered for event, in the order they were registered, passing the supplied arguments to each.

But with this simple example:

```
router.get('/messages', function(req, res, next) {
    var addMessageListener = function(res){
        messageBus.once('message', function(data){
            res.json(data);
        })
    }
    addMessageListener(res);
});

router.get('/push', function(req, res, next) {
    messageBus.emit('message', { awesome : 'event'})
    res.status(200).end()
});
```

When message event is emitted and two request are listening, only one of them listen properly to the event and execute its callback.

Is there a way to emit the event to all listeners at the same time?

**edit:**

I didnt need the listeners to execute at the exact same time, I just need to execute all of them

**edit 2:**

After more testing, when I create more than one listener, they are successfully listening to the emitter (debugged with `messageBus.listenerCount('message')`) but with an almost 20 seconds delay.

And when only one is listening and the second one is during this delay, if I call `/push` it successfully emit to the listening one and the other one immediately start listening.

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded. There is no "at the same time".

Comment: Oh sorry, I didnt mean at the same time. Just edited

Comment: Are you sure that one of your `res` hasn't timed out by the time you call `/push`? Add a `console.log(data)` or something inside your `.once()`. What you're asking for is how the `EventEmitter` works by default. Side question -- what are you trying to do, exactly? Seems like something like `socket.io` would better suit your needs.

Comment: Yes, im sure, in fact, when I have two requests pending, `/push` successfuly execute one of the listeners, and calling it again execute the other one. For your side question, I'm trying to build a long polling server with Node, just for learning, btw, what will you recommend for a real-time messaging for native mobile apps and web apps?

Answer (score 1):

Since you used the  [once()](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_once_event_listener) function to add the listener, node will call the specified listener at most *once*, and after the first call it will remove that listener. If you are expecting the listener to be called every time a `message` event is emitted, you need to use the [on()](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_event_listener) function instead of `once()`.

Comment: I actually need the listener to be called just `once()`, what I need is to call **every** existing listener

Answer (score 0):

Ok reading [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129672/handling-multiple-parallel-http-requests-in-node-js#comment24788838_17129707) I found that when testing, Chrome will not request the same url again after the first one was responded or after the mentioned delay.

Sorry about that.