# How to Handle Multiple user request at the same time in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, async-await, node-async

I have created a route `'/api/checkUsername'`. Which action is to check if there is any user exists with the `same username`. If not Save the new `UserName` in users collection and update the users count in another collection.

For the route, I have a function as

```
async function(username) {
   IsUserNameExists = await db.findOne({ 'username': username });

   if(IsUserNameExists) {
      res.send({ message: 'username already exists');  
  }else{
      await user.save() //to save user in DB
      await updateUserCount() //update user count in collection 2 
      res.send({ message: 'user saved successfully' });
  } 

}
```

This works fine with all use cases. But a case like if 2 users [`'user1', 'user2'`] user check for the same username `eg: Tony_Stark` at the same second or with few milli-second difference.

`eg` user1 and user2 hits `/api/checkUsername` at the same time or with millisecond difference. user 1 finds that username `Tony_Stark` is available and saving his username, but in between saving the user name the user2 also looks for the username `Tony_Stark` which has not been saved by user1, So it makes that username available for user2 also. Which creates a duplicate entry in my collection. How do I avoid this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling multiple parallel HTTP requests in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129672/handling-multiple-parallel-http-requests-in-node-js)

Comment: No @Raymond that is similar. But actually my code has a series of nested functions to get completed before saving the user in DB. The user 2 is not waiting for it to get completed since it is asynchronous. I'm expecting this to work synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using the mutex as this is a problem of mutual execution using the library async-mutex

```
npm install async-mutex

or

yarn add async-mutex
```

So your solution will look like

```
import { Mutex, MutexInterface } from 'async-mutex';

const mutex = new Mutex();

createUser = async (userName) => {
    mutex
    .acquire()
    .then(async (release) => {
                try {
                    const IsUserNameExists = await db.findOne({ 'username': username });
                    if (!IsUserNameExist) {
                        // ... Statement to create user
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                } finally {
                    release();
                }
            },
}
```